# Using sed substitution, how can I add spaces at the end?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to insert a space in the middle so that the string

```
up 2 days, 12:32
```

becomes

```
up 2 days,  12:32
```

I've been trying to do this using sed substitution. My `sed` function looks like

```
sed 's/,/, /'
```

And I feel like that should work, but trailing whitespaces are being ignored.

I've tried using '\' to see if I could escape whitespaces. I'm not sure what's going on because spaces before the comma aren't being discarded. I feel like this is asked a lot, but I haven't found anything that works for me.

**EDIT: This is the full command that I call `sed` in**

```
echo "    "`uptime | cut -d ' ' -f3-6 | sed 's/,$//' | sed 's/,/, /'`
```

I expect the output to be

```
up 2 days,  12:32
```

but instead I got

```
up 2 days, 12:32
```

Comment: `echo 'up 2 days, 12:32' | sed 's/,/, /'` outputs as you expected.

Comment: Where is the second comma? I can see only one in your sample input. For global replace, append `g` flag: `sed 's/,/, /g'`.

Comment: I misread you're first comment. You are right it does. I am going to add a little more information. The `sed` is part of a pipe of instructions.

Comment: Please show us all the commands in said pipe, and what you expect it to have done.

Comment: Thanks guys. Here is the full pipe

Comment: The current output is `up 2 days , 12`. Is it that you transposed space and comma on purpose?

Comment: Whoops! I was fiddling around with it and forgot to put it back. It's back to how I originally wrote it. No that was an accident

Comment: What is your objective, to single out the up time from the output of uptime?

Comment: The problem isn't with sed.  The problem is with echo.  echo takes parameters and prints them space separated.  Try `echo asd       qwe` (with many spaces between asd and qwe) for example.  You need to put quotes around the parameter to echo so that it is one parameter instead of many.

Comment: That's correct. it's to single out the output of uptime

Comment: Then doesn't  uptime -p  work for you?

Comment: I have a strict formatting guideline to follow. Otherwise I would use `uptime -p`. That's definitely a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jerry suggestion, put backticks inside double quotes:

```
echo "    `uptime | cut -d ' ' -f3-6 | sed 's/,$//' | sed 's/,/, /'`"
```

As @tripleee suggestion, here is a shorter solution, `sed` called once:

```
uptime|sed 's:,  .*$::;s:, :,  :;s:^.*up:    up:'
            ^          ^         ^
            |__________|_________|___ s:,*  .*$::     remove ',  ' (2 spaces) to end
                       |_________|___ s:, :,  :       add one space after ','
                                 |___ s:^.*up:    up: add spaces before 'up'
```

It works with both single day, or multiple days. Test:

```
$ a=' 12:02:45 up  1:09,  1 user,  load average: 0.06, 0.13, 0.16'
$ b=' 12:02:45 up  2 days, 20:30,  1 user,  load average: 0.06, 0.13, 0.16'
$ sed 's:,  .*$::;s:, :,  :;s:^.*up:    up:' <<<"$a"
     up  1:09
$ sed 's:,  .*$::;s:, :,  :;s:^.*up:    up:' <<<"$b"
     up  2 days,  20:30
```

Comment: And probably add the leading spaces with `sed` as well instead of the ugly `echo` with backticks; and refactor the `sed | sed` (which should not now turn into `sed | sed | sed`!) into a single script.

Comment: `uptime | cut -d ' ' -f3-6 | sed 's/,$//;s/,/, /;s/^/____/'` <- I can't get multiple adjacent spaces in a `code` block in a comment so I put a few underscores instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe keep everything simple - why does it have to be echoed when sed or awk will output to stdout anyway? This is using the output of GNU `uptime` - i don't know whether it varies at all though, so may need tweaking

```
uptime | 
awk '{ 
  printf "%s %s %s,  %s\n", $2, $3, $4, substr($5,0,5) 
}'
```

You may want to correct the formatting as well, to add some spaces at the start

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a single call to `sed` and backreferences if you like, e.g.

```
$ uptime | 
sed 's/^[^u]*\(up [0-9][0-9]* days*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]*:[0-9][0-9]\).*$/\1,  \2/'
up 1 day,  11:02
```

or a machine with multiple days (same regex):

```
$ uptime | 
sed 's/^[^u]*\(up [0-9][0-9]* days*\)[^0-9]*\([0-9][0-9]*:[0-9][0-9]\).*$/\1,  \2/'
up 134 days,  4:19
```

The basic regex simply locates `up digits day(s)` and then the `hours:minutes` (captured as backreference `\1` and `\2`) and then forms the final substitution with `\1,  \2` (you can enter as many (or few) spaces as you like)